# runnable pseudocode?

Tags: language-agnostic, translation, pseudocode, transpiler

I am attempting to determine prior art for the following idea:

1) user types in some code in a language called (insert_name_here);

2) user chooses a destination language from a list of well-known output candidates (javascript, ruby, perl, python);

3) the processor translates insert_name_here into runnable code in destination language;

4) the processor then runs the code using the relevant system call based on the chosen language

The reason this works is because there is a pre-established 1 to 1 mapping between all language constructs from insert_name_here to all supported destination languages.

(**Disclaimer:** This obviously does not produce "elegant" code that is well-tailored to the destination language. It simply does a rudimentary translation that is runnable. The purpose is to allow developers to get a quick-and-dirty implementation of algorithms in several different languages for those cases where they do not feel like re-inventing the wheel, but are required for whatever reason to work with a specific language on a specific project.)

Does this already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are converters available for different languages.  The problem you are going to have is dealing with libraries.  While mapping between language statements might be easy, finding mappings between library functions will be very difficult.

I'm not really sure how useful that type of code generator would be.  Why would you want to write something in one language and then immediately convert it to something else?  I can see the rationale for 4th Gen languages that convert diagrams or models into code but I don't really see the point of your effort.

Answer (score 5):

The .NET CLR is designed such that C++.Net, C#.Net, and VB.Net all compile to the same machine language, and you can "decompile" that CLI back in to any one of those languages.

So yes, I would say it already exists though not exactly as you describe.

Comment: Indeed, and with Red Gate's Reflector tool you can trivially convert between languages.

Comment: "not exactly as you describe" is what the software patent system is built on, unfortunately. You can turn a two-step process into a one-step process and make that patentable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a program that transform a program from one representation to another *does* exist. It's called a "compiler".

And as to your question whether that is always possible: as long as your target language is at least as powerful as the source language, then it is possible. So, if your target language is Turing-complete, then it is *always* possible, because there can be no language that is more powerful than a Turing-complete language.

However, there does not need to be a dumb 1:1 mapping.

For example: the Microsoft Volta compiler which compiles CIL bytecode to JavaScript sourcecode has a problem: .NET has threads, JavaScript doesn't. But you can implement threads with continuations. Well, JavaScript doesn't have continuations either, but you can implement continuations with exceptions. So, Volta transforms the CIL to CPS and then implements CPS with exceptions. (Newer versions of JavaScript have semi-coroutines in the form of generators; those could also be used, but Volta is intended to work across a wide range of JavaScript versions, including obviously JScript in Internet Explorer.)

Answer (score 2):

This seems a little bizarre. If you're using the term "prior art" in its most common form, you're discussing a potentially patentable idea. If that **is** the case, you have:

1/ Published the idea, starting the clock running on patent filing - I'm assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that you're based in the U.S. Other jurisdictions may have other rules.

2/ Told the entire planet your idea, which means it's pretty much useless to try and patent it, unless you act very fast.

If you're not thinking about patenting this and were just using the term "prior art" in a laypersons sense, I apologize. I work for a company that takes patents very seriously and it's drilled into us, in great detail, what we're allowed to do with information before filing.

Having said that, patentable ideas must be novel, useful and non-obvious. I would think that your idea would not pass on the third of these since you're describing a language translator which would have the prior art of the many pascal-to-c and fortran-to-c converters out there.

The one glimmer of hope would be the ability of your idea to generate one of multiple output languages (which p2c and f2c don't do) but I think even that would be covered by the likes of cross compilers (such as gcc) which turn source into one of many different object languages.

IBM has a product called Visual Age Generator in which you code in one (proprietary) language and it's converted into COBOL/C/Java/others to run on different target platforms from PCs to the big honkin' System z mainframes, so there's your first problem (thinking about patenting an idea that IBM, the biggest patenter in the world, is already using).

Answer (score 2):

Tons of them.  p2c, f2c, and the original implementation s of C++ and Objective C strike me immediately.  Beyond that, it's kind of hard to distinguish what you're describing from any compiler, especially for us old guys whose compilers generated ASM code for an intermediate represetation anyway.